# How does Hexar.io determine what area the player has captured

Tags: lua

I'm writing a game in lua and am looking for an efficient solution to determine what area a player has captured like Hexar.io

I can't post images, here's an example picture from hexar.io

https://ibb.co/iw5fdF

I managed to make a blocky grid system, with movement for the players. But I'm having trouble determining what area to capture based off the first capture point, and the end point for the drawing.

Any help is appreciated - Ryan

Comment: Flood fill non-player cells starting from infinity (very far-away cells on the field). The set of cells that are not filled is exactly what has been captured